# Primary and secondary color for ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic scss have 9 default color variable, which are `$light`, `$stable`, `$positive`, `$calm`, `$balanced`, `$energized`, `$assertive`, `$royal` and `$dark`.

My question is: 
If i would like to set primary and secondary color, which variable are the most suitable choice to change?

I am refering to ionic 1. Ionic 2 on the other hand, have `$primary` and `$secondary` variable by default.